# Including fixed-time transitions into a continuous time Markov chain system

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have system which is mostly described by a [CTMC (Continuous-time Markov chain)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain) with a single absorbing state and a large but tractable and sparse transition matrix. However, at a fixed set of "switch times" $\{t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n\}$, we intervene to enforce a transition with probability $1$ which depends on the current state at the time, but is deterministic otherwise. For example, it could send state $i$ to state $i+1$. Then we restart the CTMC dynamics from there, until the next switch time.

This system can be simulated easily enough. We run the CTMC, and as soon the first event should occur which puts us over a switch time $t_i$, we instead enforce the predetermined transition and set the time to exactly $t_i$. Then continue onwards simulating CTMC dynamics from this new state. This should be fine because of the memoryless property.

I would like to understand this system better without relying solely on simulations, but I can't find any existing theory about this situation. I'm particularly interested in things like the absorption time (phase type distribution), first passage times, etc.

If there was only one switch time, I think we could break down the expected time to absorption into parts by tracking paths between switch times - that is, using the probability that the system absorbed before or after t and the probability of being in each state at time t. But tracking all possible paths between switch times like this seems like it would become quickly intractable with many switch times.

Any thoughts welcome.

Comment: I don't think that your model is treated in the literature explicitely. But it is simple to break the process into parts from $[0,t_1)$, $[t_1,t_2)$, ..., then to compute the corresponding transitions in these timeintervals as $p_* e^{t_1 Q}$, $p_* e^{(t_2-t_1)Q}$, $\ldots$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain) and $p_*$ is the transition after a time period. If the time intervals do not have equal length you get an inhomogenous MC, otherwise  even a time homogenous MC. Of course for calculating the probabilities you want, you have to consider the time between.